# В цикле бот игнорирует register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telebot, for, while

Я создаю бота на пайтоне с помощью библиотеки telebot(pyTelegramBotAPI), при запуске этого кода и нажатия /start бот начинает спамить сообщением, а должен ждать мое сообщение.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
def test(message):
    print(1)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    for i in range(5):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи сообщение.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message,test)
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Покажите код функции ```test```

Comment: @arnold в коде написано print(1), а оно не выводит в консоль ничего, и просто 5 раз отправляет сообщение Введи сообщение.